# Is it possible to pass a function as another function parameter?

Tags: php, function

This is `page1.php`:

```
function config($key): ?string 
{
    $arr = ["protocol" => "https",
            "port"     => "80",
            "website"  => "wwww.example.com"];
    return array_key_exists($key, $arr) ? $arr[$key] : null;
}
```

And this is `page2.php`:

```
function ckeckDomain($protocol, $port, $website, $user_role): bool
{
    if ( $user_role === "admin" ){
        // we need $protocol, $port and $website here 
    }
}
```

And here is `page3.php`:

```
 require "page1.php";
 require "page2.php";

 if ( checkDomain(config("protocol"), config("port"), config("website"), $_SESSION["user_role"]) ){
    // do stuff
 }
```

Ok well, as you can see, I have to pass `config("protocol")`, `config("port")`, `config("website")` arguments separately to `checkDomain` function. Now I want to know is it possible to I pass `config` function to `checkDomain`, and then call `config` function into `checkDomain` function scope?

Something like this:

```
if ( checkDomain( /* config function */, $_SESSION["user_role"] ) ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: @eol My question is about scope accessibility.

Comment: You're currently passing *values* into `checkDomain`. You want to replace that with passing a function? So `checkDomain` would do `$config('protocol')`? Then the above duplicate is perfectly adequate. Not really seeing much significance of scope.

Comment: @deceze `ckeckDomain()` and `config()` aren't in the same page. Is `config()` accessible into `ckeckDomain()` block if I pass it to `ckeckDomain`?

Comment: Functions don't have any scope. If you have `require`d the file the function is defined in somewhere once, then the function is defined and accessible everywhere.